# MySql COUNT() function not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the top blog poster from our mysql db

This currently works for part of it:

```
SELECT `username` , COUNT( `owner_id` ) AS Occurences, `owner_id`
FROM `engine4_blog_blogs` , `engine4_users`   
WHERE `engine4_users`.`user_id` = `owner_id`  
GROUP BY `owner_id`
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
LIMIT 1
```

which produces:

```
username / Occurences / owner_id    
jack91  /    10      /      4
```

Which is correct.

Now what I need is to also get the persons thumbnail icon registered to them as well so I try this:

```
SELECT `username` , COUNT( `engine4_blog_blogs`.`owner_id` ) AS Occurences, `owner_id`, `storage_path`
FROM `engine4_blog_blogs` , `engine4_users`, `engine4_storage_files`   
WHERE `engine4_users`.`user_id` = `engine4_blog_blogs`.`owner_id` AND `engine4_users`.`user_id` = `engine4_storage_files`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `engine4_blog_blogs`.`owner_id`
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
LIMIT 1
```

which produces:

```
username /  Occurences /    owner_id /  storage_path    
jack91 /    2480 /  4 / (public/user/1f/001f_250b.JPG)
```

The username, owner_id & storage_path is correct but what is the db counting as this value for Occurences is not correct? I thought by specifying  `COUNT(`engine4_blog_blogs`.`owner_id`)` it would only count that field only - also I must add that the column field `owner_id` only exists in engine4_blog_blogs table.

Now I have tried various permutations including JOINS, INNER JOINS and LEFT JOINS and all produce the same result... An incorrect count().

Basically I am looking for this output:

```
username /  Occurences /    owner_id /  storage_path    
jack91 /    10 /    4 / (public/user/1f/001f_250b.JPG)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong (plz keep in mind I have not touched sql in over 10 years)?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that user_id 4 (username jack91) currently has 10 blog posts ?

Comment: You should be counting posts, not users. So `COUNT(DISTINCT engine4_blog_blogs.blog_id ) AS Occurences` (assuming that `blog_id` is primary key of `engine4_blog_blogs`)

Comment: Correct! The user has only 10 blog posts which is the greatest amount in that table for any user.

Comment: blog_id is primary key but its an auto-incrementing field, the owner_id is the only repeating data field.  Table looks like this  -  blog_id,  title,  body,  owner_type,  owner_id,  category_id,  creation_date,  modified_date

Comment: You `JOIN` by owner id. But to count, how many posts an owner has - you count unique IDs of posts.

Comment: create a fiddle with SQL structure - and we'll be able to help with mode details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make grouping work *correctly*. you must group by all non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT `username` , COUNT( DISTINCT `engine4_blog_blogs`.`blog_id` ) AS Occurences, `owner_id`, `storage_path`
FROM `engine4_blog_blogs` , `engine4_users`, `engine4_storage_files`   
WHERE `engine4_users`.`user_id` = `engine4_blog_blogs`.`owner_id` AND `engine4_users`.`user_id` = `engine4_storage_files`.`user_id`
GROUP BY 1,3,4
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You also want to add the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `COUNT()` to get the number of *differently* authored blogs.*

Mysql supports non-standard grouping syntax - if you stick with the standard, it will work as you expect.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!  I knew I was forgetting something simple. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my comment as answer.

You are counting owner_id. But should be counting his posts.
So, instead of

```
COUNT( `owner_id` ) AS Occurences
```

do

```
COUNT(DISTINCT engine4_blog_blogs.blog_id)
```

Assuming that `blog_id` is primary key of `engine4_blog_blogs`